# No Dig option in Dogecoin-QT?

Tags: miner-configuration, dogecoin, cpu-mining

I have seen, in numerous screenshots of Dogecoin-QT, a "dig" pane (equivalent to "mine" in some others):
[image]
However, my client has no such pane:
[image]
Does anyone know where that option has gone? Was it removed in an upgrade?

Comment: Dogecoin is on-topic, otherwise we wouldn't have a tag, would we? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was removed in an update. The developers have decided to hide it as a way to discourage users from wasting CPU time. CPU mining this big of a coin will get you no where.

It's suggested to mine using an external mining program like CGMiner or practically any miner recommended for Scrypt. Check out [Litecoin wiki's Mining Software list](https://litecoin.info/Mining_software) and look into Scrypt mining guides such as the [Dogecoin wiki's 'Beginners guide'.](http://dogecoin.wikia.com/wiki/Beginners_guide_to_Dogecoin#Digging_.28Mining_for_DogeCoins.29)

Comment: Thanks, I am already mining using minerd (cpuminer). I just wondered where the option had gone, that's all.